# How can I cut down on the number of event listeners for buttons in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery 1.6.2.

Basically in one of my pages, I have a structure that looks like:

```
<div id="section1">
    <fieldset>
        <ul>
            <li>
             <input type="radio" name="1" value="">blah 1</input></li>
            <li>
             <input type="radio" name="1" value="" checked="checked">
             blah 2</input>
            </li>
            <li>
             <input type="radio" name="1" value="">blah 3</input>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div>
            ....snipped...
            <button type='submit' id='button1'/>
        </div> 
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

And because I have 100 such structures; I have the equivalent 100 event click handlers of this sort:

```
var name = "1";
$('#button1')
    .parent().parent()
    .find("input:radio[name='" + name + "']")
    .filter(':checked')
    .attr('value');
```

Is there a way to simplify this with one event listener ?

Comment: That code doesn't seem to do anything useful (it retrieves the `value` of an element and then discards it). What are you trying to do?

Comment: Those are not click event handlers in your code. That is finding and changing values. Do you actually have `bind()` or `click()` in your code?

Comment: I believe you actually omitted the event click handler.  What are you clicking?

Comment: I have lots of click()s in my code. Sorry I didn't actually display the event handler but I have individual event handler for each selectors `#button1`, `#button2`, `#button3` etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, with jQuery, you'd use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to reduce the number of event listeners.

Comment: You haven't shown any event listener binding code, though, so it's difficult to answer any more specifically.

Comment: that would reduce the actual code (less text), but would not reduce the amount of behind the scenes listening going on ...

Answer (score 1):

Add a common class to all the buttons like this:

```
<button class="submitButton" type='submit' id='button1'/>
```

Then, you can define one click handler like this that will bind to all those buttons with the same behavior:

```
$(".submitButton").click(function() {
    // put whatever code you want here for all submit buttons
});
```

If you need to know which button it is that is being pressed, you can fetch the id value and get the number off that:

```
$(".submitButton").click(function() {
    var num = parseInt(this.id.match(/\d+/)[0], 10);
    // now you can process the submit knowing the num 
    // is the number at the end of the buttom id
});
```

Or, you could put a data item on the button like this:

```
<button class="submitButton" data-num="1" type='submit' id='button1'/>
```

And, you can then retrieve that number like this:

```
$(".submitButton").click(function() {
    var num = $(this).data("num");
    // now you can process the submit knowing the num 
    // is the number at the end of the buttom id
});
```

Comment: I'd imagine that this _still_ creates a hundred different handler references silently -- that is, you just don't need to type in a bulk of code. The question is a bit ambiguous, but if the asker wants to minimize on the number of actual handler instances, then it might be worthy to note that `.delegate` would seem like a better option.

Comment: @richardneililagan - agree, it still creates a listener for every button. Better to put the listener on the div with id *secton1* and get the button using *event.target* or *event.srcElement*.

Comment: @RobG - Why not put the listener on the button right where the event occurs?  Why put it on a parent?

Comment: @jfriend00 ~ by putting it on the parent (and waiting for the event to bubble up to it, like with `.delegate()`), you only put in one handler that handles every single event for hundreds, or even thousands of elements. If you put the handler on the button, and have thousands of those buttons, that means thousands of individual handlers (that more or less do the same thing), and that doesn't sound so good.

Comment: @richardneililagan - all you've said is it doesn't "sound" so good.  I'd like to know why your method is actually better?

Comment: @jfriend00 ~ one instance of an object versus a hundred instances that do the same thing. sorry to sound rude, but what's there to explain? If that's not readily apparent, here's a good explanation of what I'm trying to get at. http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/ :)

Comment: @richardneililagan - I still haven't heard any benefit one way or the other.    Your referenced article just explains `.delegate`, but doesn't address this particular question.  If you want an analogy, I think it's more efficient to dial someone directly than to have everyone go through the operator in order to connect their call.  It's not always more efficient for everything to go through one central choke point.  Sometimes, hooking up directly to the desired object is more efficient, not less.

Comment: I honestly don't know one way or the other, but I feel like one shouldn't be saying one way is or isn't more efficient without some actual data and I haven't yet seen or heard any yet.

Comment: I'm referencing an article to what (I hope) is someone's work on actually benchmarking the thing. Around halfway down the article is an explicit statement on the assumed perf benefits of attaching one handler to handle many, as opposed to singular instance attachments. Scroll down to *why .live() or .delegate() instead of .bind()*, and check out the second bullet point. But you're right, I've never benched it before; I'm just here on postulate. But like I said on my first comment, it _might_ be worthy of note.

Comment: That says there might be a performance benefit in configuring the event handlers (which I could potentially believe), but doesn't say anything about the performance of the actual event handlers in operation (which is what I thought we were discussing).  In any case, I think we've uncovered what data there is so no need to discuss further.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid, button elements must have a closing tag:

```
<div id="section1">
    <fieldset>
        <ul>
            <li>
             <input type="radio" name="1" value="">blah 1</input></li>
            <li>
             <input type="radio" name="1" value="" checked="checked">
             blah 2</input>
            </li>
            <li>
             <input type="radio" name="1" value="">blah 3</input>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div>
            ....snipped...
            <button id='button1' type="submit">click me</button>
        </div> 
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

You can attach a click listener to the parent *div* that only responds to buttons that are type submit:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var el = document.getElementById('section1');
  el.onclick = handleClick;
}

function handleClick(evt) {
  var evt = evt || window.event;
  var el = evt.target || evt.srcElement;

  if (el && el.tagName && el.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'button' &&
      el.type == 'submit') {
    alert('clicked button with id ' + el.id);
  }
}
```